# Segmentation fault when allocating array on the heap

Tags: c

Suppose I declare a global array on heap with a size that exceed the limit of the heap. Of course the segmentation fault will be thrown. My question is, what happens when we do that? Will the extra integers overwrite some parts in our computer system?

Comment: No. That's the reason for segmentation faults: the operating system is protecting the other processes.

Comment: When you run out of heap space, you get `NULL` returns from `malloc` and `realloc`.  You don't get segmentation faults.  Segmentations faults indicate you've misused a pointer.

Comment: When you try to write to memory you don't own, you get the segmentation fault *instead of* successfully writing to the memory you don't own.  So, no, you will not manage to "overwrite some parts in our computer system".

Comment: @SteveSummit the limit of the heap is essentially that of virtual address space on modern operating systems unless the operating system applies a limit to the process

Comment: @jordan.goe: did you mean 'the heap' here or 'the stack'?  The latter seems more likely in the context of it being global.

Comment: @SteveSummit to be more precise, writing to memory that you don't own is define as *undefined behaviour* in both C and C++.  it *may* result in an exception (not always called a segmentation fault) but could equally result in all other kinds of unintended consequences.

Comment: @SteveSummit first of all there is no way of declaring global array on the heap :)

Comment: It is not possible to declare any global array on the heap. The heap is (an informal and not entirely correct name for) an area of memory that is allocated and deallocated dynamically (e.g. using `malloc()` and `free()`). So the statement "of course the segmentation fault will be thrown" is fiction. A segmentation fault occurs when a (unix) operating system detects a process accessing memory not allocated to it, and sends a signal to forceably terminate the process.  The OS is protecting the memory to prevent the process accessing memory it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the operating system you are using (if any).

**Systems that provides a [process virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) abstraction - that is to say any *nix variant, Windows, some RTOSs such as QNX**

In these systems, there is a distinction between virtual memory (address space) and committed physical pages.  The process gains physical pages when the writes occurs to the associated virtual address space. Thus it is possible to allocate a larger heap-block than there is physical memory on the system, and the heap can grow on demand.  The system may use [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) to maintain a working set of pages backed by real memory,  and write those that can't be accommodated to disk.  This is what many people (incorrectly) describe as 'virtual memory'. Notably, iOS, Android and many embedded systems don't have a pager.

The operating system is likely to kill your process if it uses memory abusively  - for instance, allocating a huge heap-block and then writing randomly to all of it.  An operating system might apply a limit to the virtual address space or number of physical pages a process can have and will terminate the process when this is exceeded.

Overrunning the end of a heap-block is *undefined behaviour* in C. This may generate an exception - or any other unexpected consequence.  It's a moot point whether you have overrun the entire heap as well at this point.

All of these operating systems will prevent trashing of system memory by a process.

**Bare-metal systems, some embedded operating systems**

These systems lack the process virtual machine abstraction and memory protection that goes with it; they lack paging and will typically not allow an allocation of a larger heap-block than can be accommodated in physical pages.  Overwriting the end of an allocated block will have undefined behaviour.

Comment: No. Paging does not matter. if you set the heap to `N` bytes large if you try to allocate more than it is free (ie `N` minus already allocated memory), the allocation function will return NULL. No segfaults./

Comment: @P__J__: the heap limit is essentially that of virtual address space on all modern operating systems - it's probably less than 2^64 on most 64-bit systems, but still significantly large. 

There may well be a limit applied in the standard C-library, or the process will  run into an rlimit of the maximum virtual address space.

On embedded systems, having `malloc()` return `NULL` is a definitely possibility.  On general purpose operating systems, you'd have to try quite hard for this to happen.

Comment: it can be but it **does not** have to be. BTW in the uC development we try to avoid any dynamic allocations. Some programing standards ban it completely so that case is much less interesting

Comment: Sure - I think my answer above made this case.  The problem on embedded systems is that general purpose heap implementations rarely offer `O(1)` allocation and deallocation performance nad have potential to generate priority inversions.
I strongly suspect the OP is not using an RTOS or bare-metal system.

Comment: it is not the main issue. The main issue is fragmentation of the heap.

Comment: to be pedantic, hence why the allocator can never be `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose I declare a global array on heap with a size that exceed the limit of the heap.

You cant declare the the global array on the heap as you do not have access to this memory at the compile time.

Probably you mean the array with the static storage duration and if the size of it will be larger than the memory reserved for the static storage duration objects the linker will throw the error.

**heap** memory can be only dynamically allocated runtime using the `malloc` family functions.

```
int a[500]; // 'a' is a static storage duration object

int foo()
{
   int b[500]; //'b' is an automatic storage duration object (most implementations use stack for it)
   static int c[500]; // 'c' is a static storage duration object
   int *d; //'d' is an automatic storage duration pointer (most implementations use 

   d = malloc(1000); // 'd' references the 1000 byte memory area allocated on the heap
}
```

if you try to allocate more memory than is available the allocation function will return `NULL` but not fail. 
If you try to access the memory which does not belongs to the object - it is an Undefined Behavior and it may potentially result in the segmentation fault.